# CS:GO Mouse Configuration like CS:S

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse, counter-strike-source

I am an experienced Counter Strike: Source player and very used to its controls (especially its mouse controls).

Just some days ago I bought Counter Strike Global Offensive and started playing it. Well, the game was good, but I didn't find the mouse controls comfortable.

I think it is something related to mouse acceleration and speed but I'm not sure. I saw some guides on the Internet but they didn't work or they were too complicated.

I am looking for a set of simple steps which will make CS:GO's mouse controls just like CS:S (because i'm very used to them). Is this possible? How would I go about it?

Comment: I don't think you will find any simple steps. Whatever you find the perfect settings on CS:S isn't the same for someone else, and based on your question it's difficult to discern if you think mouse acceleration is bad or good, or if higher speed is better or worse for you. The best thing to do is devote some time to actually slowly play with the settings and test out what you consider to be the best controls for you.

Answer (score 1):

Which settings are the 'perfect' settings is impossible to answer, because each person has their own preferences, however there are some settings to attempt on your own to achieve "perfection."

These are my current settings, and they've worked pretty well for me. I currently own a Razer Deathadder 2013, at default settings.

This is the In game menu in CS:GO to change mouse settings. I'd recommend only playing with the Sensitivity Settings or the Acceleration Amount. Everything else should be set to default.

[image: my current settings]

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would suggest is going into your mouse properties and turning **off** enhance pointer precision. This can have a similar effect to mouse acceleration which you also want to turn off so that an equal mouse movement always corresponds to an equal movement of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both games run on the same engine, using the same settings file.  Copy your config.cfg file from your CS:S directory for you CS:GO directory, and it should just work.

Comment: That might break CSGO as it is using a different version of the engine.